# What's the number of subgroup of order 17 in $Z_{17}\times Z_{17}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It seems like there is a method to solve this kind of problem. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "$Z_{17}*Z_{17}$". Most of the time that's an infinite group with infinitely many subgroups of order $17$. If you mean $\mathbb Z_{17}\times\mathbb Z_{17}$ then there are finitely many.

Comment: oh I mean the latter. Sorry for confusion. It's a direct product

Comment: How about $(17^2-1)/16 = 18$ ??

Comment: Every element but the identity has order $17$; every subgroup of order $17$ has $16$ elements of order $17$, all of which generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any group of order 17 is  cyclic. So, in order to find subgroup of order 17 in    $\mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_{17}$ we need to look at the elements of order 17 first and consider the subgroup generated by them.

It is like you are counting sheep by counting their legs but then to get the genuine number of sheep you have to divide the number obtained previously by 4.
Here, number of elements are going to be the number of legs.

Any element of order 17 in $\mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_{17}$ is of the form $(a,0), (0,b), (a,b) $ where $a, b$ are elements of order $17$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}\\.$

For each  such $a$ and $b$, we have 16 choices because in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ orders are either 1 or 17 and only identity have order 1. $\\$

Number of elements of the form $(a,0)$ are 16 and subgroups generated by them will be the same because any subgroup will contain each element of this form. Therefore, we get only one subgroup in this case.$\\$

Number of elements of the form $(0,b)$ are 16 and subgroups generated by them will be the same because any subgroup will contain each element of this form. Therefore, we get only one subgroup in this case.$ \\$

Number of elements of the form $(a,b)$ are $16^2$ and only 16 subgroups are different.

Hence, there are only 18 subgroups of order 17 in $\mathbb{Z}_{17} \times \mathbb{Z}_{17}.$

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I see that you mean direct product, not some other kind like free product.

We need to account for the $288$ elements of order $17$.

Since the order is prime any two different ones intersect trivially.

In this case there are $16$ different elements of order $17$ per subgroup.

Thus we get $288/16=18$.

If we do this for any prime $p$, we get $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1$ subgroups of order $p$.